In microservices application containing Spring boot projects as services, not able to access the business service using the api gateway
I am new to microservices , am facing an issue and am unable to resolve it. I need your help please.
I have created 4 spring boot applications for working with microservices.They are configserver1, discovery , gateway and the business service employeeService1.After I start up all the modules, employeeService1 is getting registered with the discovery server. I am also able to bring up employeeService1 using its port 3000 -> localhost:3000.
But I am unable to access employeeService1 through the api gateway.When I type localhost:8222/api/v1/employees it gives me 404 error. I have uploaded the code to GitHub and here is the link to my github:   https://github.com/Asha2144877?tab=repositories. And the repositories are configserver1,gateway,discovery and employeeService1.
Can you please take a look and help me resolve this issue.I am not sure what I am missing.
I tried the link http://localhost:8222/api/v1/employees. I expected the employee business service to start up using the gateway , but it is throwing 404 error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have placed the code at https://github.com/Asha2144877?tab=repositories.
